# How to create a function in R that call a name only when a threshold is reached?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a variable that increase 1 unit every day (let's call it `cumulative date`). You calculate this `cumulative date` for days 1 to 10. I want to create a second variable that is called `phase`. The phases are "phase1", "phase2", and "phase3". These phases are reached when `cumulative date` is 2.6, 6.3, and 8.3 or larger, respectively. I want to create a function in R that does this, but the trick is that I want the phases only be added when the criteria is met.

This is my code:

```
create_phase <- function(cumulative_date) {
  phase <- case_when(
    cumulative_date >= 8.3 ~ "phase3",
    cumulative_date >= 6.3 ~ "phase2",
    cumulative_date >= 2.6 ~ "phase1"
  )
  return(phase)
}

cumulative_date <- 1:10
phase <- cbind(cumulative_date, create_phase(cumulative_date))
```

This is the result, which is close to what I need:

[image]

But what I really need is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you might consider using `lag` and then check when crosses threshold to label the phase.

```
library(tidyverse)

create_phase <- function(cumulative_date) {
  phase <- case_when(
    lag(cumulative_date) < 8.3 & cumulative_date >= 8.3 ~ "phase3",
    lag(cumulative_date) < 6.3 & cumulative_date >= 6.3 ~ "phase2",
    lag(cumulative_date) < 2.6 & cumulative_date >= 2.6 ~ "phase1"
  )
  return(phase)
}

cumulative_date <- 1:10

data.frame(cumulative_date, phase = create_phase(cumulative_date))
```

**Output**

```
   cumulative_date  phase
1                1   <NA>
2                2   <NA>
3                3 phase1
4                4   <NA>
5                5   <NA>
6                6   <NA>
7                7 phase2
8                8   <NA>
9                9 phase3
10              10   <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group your data by `phase`, and turn every but the first entry of `phase` into `NA`:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(phase = case_when(date >= 8.3 ~ "phase3",
                           date >= 6.3 ~ "phase2",
                           date >= 2.6 ~ "phase1")) %>%
  group_by(phase) %>%
  mutate(phase = c(phase[1], rep(NA, n()-1)))
```

**Dummy data:** `df1 <- tibble(date = 1:10)`

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
# Groups:   phase [4]
    date phase 
   <int> <chr> 
 1     1 NA    
 2     2 NA    
 3     3 phase1
 4     4 NA    
 5     5 NA    
 6     6 NA    
 7     7 phase2
 8     8 NA    
 9     9 phase3
10    10 NA
```

Comment: I need to do that within a function